# How to display javascript console.log in eclipse console?

Tags: javascript, eclipse

Title says it all. I am wondering if i can display javascript `console.log` in eclipse console rather than  web browser's dev console?

Comment: Related: https://code.google.com/p/chromedevtools/issues/detail?id=43

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeah, i actually read it, and was wondering if they made update after 2014.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found an [article](http://z0ltan.wordpress.com/2012/12/04/configuring-eclipse-to-run-standalone-javascript-files-using-node-jsgoogle-v8-engine/) regarding this.

This is How it works(For Window 7).

1. Install Node.js javascript engine at [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/)
2. Open your Eclipse, in the menu

   Run->External Tools->External Tools Configuration
3. Create new launch configuration under program category.
4. Set

   Location : C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe

   Working Directory : C:\WINDOWS\system32

   Argument : /c "node ${resource_loc}"
5. Now create new environment variable 'node' refers to node.exe file(wherever you installed)

All done.

Comment: That's great, but link-only answers aren't useful on SO. If you could summarize the main points *and* link, that would be useful.

Comment: I see, i will fix it soon.

Answer (score 2):

### Redirect javascript console.logs, in Java console

Here is my solution to get javascript console messages in Java (with SWT browser)

1. create shell SWT and SWT browser [see: Shell + Browser](https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet136.java)
2. create custom function SWT [see: call Java from JavaScript](https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet307.java)
3. Add listener on error events in javascript [see: mdn event error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/error_event)
4. Override console object in javascript and call custom java function (2.)

---

Here is my example snippet:

```java
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWTError;
import org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser;
import org.eclipse.swt.browser.BrowserFunction;
import org.eclipse.swt.browser.LocationAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.browser.LocationEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.browser.ProgressListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class Snippet307d3 {

    public static final Shell createShell() {
        final var display = new Display();
        final var shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setText("Snippet DEBUG");
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        shell.setBounds(10, 10, 300, 200);
        return shell;
    }

    public static final Browser createBrowser(Shell shell) {
        try {
            return new Browser(shell, SWT.NONE);
        } catch (final SWTError e) {
            System.out.println("Could not instantiate Browser: " + e.getMessage());
            shell.getDisplay().dispose();
            System.exit(-1);
            return null;
        }

    }

    public static final void runShell(Shell shell) {
        shell.open();
        final var display = shell.getDisplay();

        while (!shell.isDisposed())
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();

        display.dispose();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // -> Create shell
        final var shell = createShell();

        // -> Create browser
        final var browser = createBrowser(shell);
        browser.setJavascriptEnabled(true);

        // -> set HTML or use setUrl
        browser.setText(createHTML());
        // browser.setUrl(URL_DOCUMENT_HTML_TEST);

        // -> Create custom function
        final BrowserFunction function = new CustomFunction(browser, "theJavaFunctionDebugInEclipse");

        // -> Register function for cleanup
        browser.addProgressListener(ProgressListener.completedAdapter(event -> {
            browser.addLocationListener(new LocationAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void changed(LocationEvent event) {
                    browser.removeLocationListener(this);
                    System.out.println("left java function-aware page, so disposed CustomFunction");
                    function.dispose();
                }
            });
        }));

        // -> 6) Start shell
        runShell(shell);
    }

    private static class CustomFunction extends BrowserFunction {
        public CustomFunction(Browser browser, String name) {
            super(browser, name);
        }

        @Override
        public Object function(Object[] arguments) {
            for (final Object v : arguments)
                if (v != null)
                    System.out.println(v.toString());

            return new Object();
        }
    }

    private static String createHTML() {
        return """
                <!DOCTYPE>
                <html lang='en'>
                <head>
                <title>DEBUG SWT</title>
                <script>
                    const console = {
                        log : function(args) {
                            try {
                                theJavaFunctionDebugInEclipse('redirect > ' + args);
                            } catch (_e) {
                                return;
                            }
                        },

                        error : function(args) {
                            this.log(args);
                        },

                        exception : function(args) {
                            this.log(args);
                        },

                        debug : function(args) {
                            this.log(args);
                        },

                        trace : function(args) {
                            this.log(args);
                        },

                        info : function(args) {
                            this.log(args);
                        }
                    };

                    window.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
                        console.log(e.type + ' : ' + e.message);
                        console.log(e);
                    });
                </script>
                </head>
                <body>

                    <input id=button type='button' value='Push to Invoke Java'
                        onclick='function1();'>

                    <p>
                        <a href='http://www.eclipse.org'>go to eclipse.org</a>
                    </p>

                    <script>

                        // bad char sequence .. send error
                        eeeee

                        function function1() {
                            let result;

                            try {
                                // Call bad function java .. send log
                                result = badFunctionJava(12, false, null, [ 3.6,
                                        [ 'swt', true ] ], 'eclipse');
                            } catch (e) {
                                console.log('a error occurred: ' + e.message);
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    </script>
                </body>
                </html>
                """;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Further to [@ringord's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27889665/167745), these would be the commands for your *External Tools Configuration* on Linux:

- Location : `/home/<user>/.nvm/versions/node/<version>/bin/node` (or wherever you installed node)
- Working Directory : `/home/<user>`
- Arguments : `${container_loc}/${resource_name}`