# I need to use Eclipse console while working with javascript

Tags: javascript, eclipse

I couldn't configure my Eclipse IDE for `console.log` printing when I'm working with JavaScript.

Can someone show me a way to configure eclipse for `console.log` printing?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609316/debug-javascript-in-eclipse

Comment: i've gone through that link. Mr. @YavorIvanov. thanks for that. actually i'm already using firebug and don't want to use aptana or any browser plug in. i just want to be familiar with eclipse.

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27889545/how-to-display-javascript-console-log-in-eclipse-console

Comment: I don't know why but it didn't work for me.